# Calling asp function from div

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have creates a side list of some item which is generated dynamically.Using

```
HtmlGenericControl div1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div1.Attributes.Add("id", "div"+(index));
    div1.Attributes.Add("class", "teacher-data");
    div1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "getHighlight(this)");

    Image img = new Image();
    img.Attributes.Add("class", "teacher-image");
    HtmlGenericControl div2 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div2.Attributes.Add("class", "teacher-data-container");
    Label lbl1 = new Label();
    lbl1.Text = name + "<br/>";
    lbl1.ID = "lbl_"+ (index++);
    Label lbl2 = new Label();
    lbl2.Text = degree;
    Label lbl3 = new Label();
    lbl1.Attributes.Add("class", "teacher-info");
    lbl2.Attributes.Add("class", "teacher-info");
    lbl3.Attributes.Add("class", "teacher-info");
    div2.Controls.Add(lbl1);
    div2.Controls.Add(lbl2);
    div2.Controls.Add(lbl3);
    div1.Controls.Add(img);
    div1.Controls.Add(div2);
    teacher_containr.Controls.Add(div1);
```

What I tried is that when some one attempt a click over that  `div` tag it gets selected but here what i also want is it should call a asp.net function so that after clicking, relevant data comes over right side of it.But nothing is working.
Can we add some event or anything in div so that it calls asp.net function. I tried ajax method but it did not work.

Comment: using jQuery in your project ?

Comment: If you want some graphic changes clientside you must use javasctipt or jQuery

Comment: no graphic changes. I just want server to know that tag has been clicked

Comment: make this getHighlight() function in jquery, then use ajax to call asp function